# PostgreSQL/VBA: transaction block fail check or process

Tags: vba, postgresql, excel, t-sql

During a transaction block, if part of it fails or gets interrupted what is the best way to handle this?

I am thinking intermediate queries (see code comments) to confirm that the previous query was successful. Or is there a better way?

```
Sub SetDataProcessPriorities()

Dim cCon As New ADODB.Connection
Set cCon = Application.Run("Personal.xlsb!ConnectToPg")
Call Application.Run("Personal.xlsb!SendPgQueryOnly", "begin;", cCon)

Call Application.Run("Personal.xlsb!SendPgQueryOnly", "delete from data_proc_pri;", cCon)
    'intermediate select query here?                                                    
Call Application.Run("Personal.xlsb!SendPgQueryOnly", "insert into data_proc_pri                                              select * from data_proc_pri_store;", cCon)
    'intermediate select query here?                                                    
Call Application.Run("Personal.xlsb!SendPgQueryOnly", "commit;", cCon)
End Sub
```

I'm open to a VBA (sorry) or PostgreSQL (or both) focused solution.

Bonus question: What do you call this type of programming? Infrastructure programming?

Personal workbook code if you need it:

```
Sub SendPgQueryOnly(sSql As String, Optional cCon As ADODB.Connection, Optional sOdbcName As String = "[omitted]")
sCaller = "SendPgQueryOnly"

    Dim cnDB As New ADODB.Connection

    Dim rsRecords As New ADODB.Recordset

    If IsMissing(cCon) Or cCon Is Nothing Then
        cnDB.Open sOdbcName
        rsRecords.CursorType = 2 'adOpenDynamic
        rsRecords.Open sSql, cnDB
    Else
        rsRecords.CursorType = 2 'adOpenDynamic
        rsRecords.Open sSql, cCon 'use the passed connection obj
    End If


cleanup:
    Set rsRecords = Nothing
    Set cnDB = Nothing
End Sub

Function ConnectToPg(Optional sOdbcName As String = "[omitted]") As ADODB.Connection
    sCaller = "ConnectToPg"

    Dim cnDB As New ADODB.Connection

    cnDB.Open sOdbcName
    Set ConnectToPg = cnDB
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For transactional control you can use the BeginTrans, CommitTrans, and RollbackTrans Methods on a Connection object

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680895(v=vs.85).aspx

Whilst one has a degree of programming style and latitude given the specific problem I guess one could query the database using some Select queries to ensure that the database state was changed as expected;  if as expected then commit and if not then rollback.